# Take up a sport

Tags: collocations

I have come across a collocation dictionary from oxford(actually surfing the site at the moment) and they exemplify this collocation:

> I need to **take up** a sport to get fit.

Does **do a sport=take up** a sport mean the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. **Take up** a sport means you weren't doing it before, but now you decided you want to do it, so you **started to do it**. **To do a sport** usually means you **already have started it.**

Comment: I am not asking about 'doing a sport' I said 'do a sport'(let's stick to that exemplified verb tense above). I'd like to believe you, but now I am doubtful. Thx anyway.

Comment: **To do** a sport. Fixed it. Doesn't make a difference, what I'm saying is correct. To do a sport is different than to take up a sport. Everytime I go to the gym, I do a sport. But if I am just starting a new sport, I am taking up a sport. Verb tense DOESN'T change the entire meaning of the word. To do, and to take up, still mean different things.

Comment: Hello. Its clearer now(do a sport-taking up a sport), nailed it. However, as for verb tenses, I hate to disagree, but there is a minor difference between using 'present continuous verb' to JUST 'present tense'(that's what I'm just tryin' to say). I clearly understand what you were saying regarding 'the entire meaning', on the flip side, mine is just grammatical.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm glad I was able to a help. I'll edit my answer to reflect my comment shortly.