# Does native speaker say it that way? "take up a sport to do"

Tags: word-usage

[Take up a sport](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/157633/115654) gives an example

> I need to take up a sport to get fit.

I am aware of the meaning. The question is about the usage of "take up".

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20up%20a%20sport%20to%20do%2Ctake%20up%20a%20sport&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ctake%20up%20a%20sport%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btake%20up%20a%20sport%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTake%20up%20a%20sport%3B%2Cc0) shows "take up a sport" is common whereas "not found" for "take up a sport to"

[image]

Does native speaker say it that way? "take up a sport to do"

Is it a little bit redundant? Because the meanings of "sport" and "get fit" overlaps a lot.

Comment: Are Ngrams limited to 3 words? Because if you search for "up a sport to" it will give results, and most of them are preceded by "take".

Comment: Sorry, meant 4 words.

Comment: @ThePhoton The limit is "no more than five".

Comment: Interesting. It looks like results are spotty for longer phrases, though. Try the search for "up a sport to" and you should be able to confirm that "take up a sport to" is not an unknown phrase.

Comment: What do you imagine "take up a sport to do" means?  Would it be the first six words of a longer phrase (such as "take up a sport to do in my free time")?